# flutter create users with email and password using Firebase Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

```dart
Future<void> userRegister({required String email, required String password, required phone, required String name})
 async {
       emit(socialRegisterLoadingState());
       final credential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
         .createUserWithEmailAndPassword( email: email, password: password, ) 
         .then((value) { emit(socialRegisterSuccesState());
                       }).catchError((error) {
               emit(socialRegisterErrorState(error));
                    });
        }
 if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
     socialRegisterCubit .get(context)
        .userRegister( name: nameController.text,
              phone: phoneController.text,
              email: emailController.text,
              password: passController.text); }
```

> I/FirebaseAuth(13007): Creating user with azdine@gmail.com with empty reCAPTCHA token
> W/System  (13007): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
> D/TrafficStats(13007): tagSocket(154) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
> E/RecaptchaCallWrapper(13007): Initial task failed for action RecaptchaAction(action=signUpPassword)with exception - An internal error has occurred. [ API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key. ]

This problem face me in create a user and login. I tried many solutions.

Comment: please show your code on how you handle creating user

Comment: Future<void> userRegister(
      {required String email,
      required String password,
      required phone,
      required String name}) async {
    emit(socialRegisterLoadingState());

    final credential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    )
        .then((value) {
      emit(socialRegisterSuccesState());
    }).catchError((error) {
      emit(socialRegisterErrorState(error));
    });
  }

Comment: if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                                    socialRegisterCubit
                                        .get(context)
                                        .userRegister(
                                            name: nameController.text,
                                            phone: phoneController.text,
                                            email: emailController.text,
                                            password: passController.text);
                                  }

Comment: Please don't put the code into comments, where it's pretty much unreadable. Instead, click the little edit link under your question, put the code into the question itself, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.